# Gremlin - how to flatten grouped output

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

The following query groups every given input vertex with their neighboring vertices and currency pair between them, which is followed by two aggregation functions, sum and count, on each set of grouped edges.

```
gremlin> g.V([2367552, 2367728]).as("v0")
              .bothE().as("e")
              .otherV().as("v1")
              .select("e").values("currency").as("c")
              .select("v0","e","v1","c")
              .group()
                  .by(select("v0","v1","c"))
                  .by(fold().match(__.as("x").count(local).as("count"), 
                                   __.as("x").unfold().select("e").by("trxn_amt").sum().as("sum")).select("count","sum"))

==>{{v0=v[2367552], v1=v[2343088], c=USD}={count=1, sum=12082.0595703125}, {v0=v[2367728], v1=v[2338888], c=USD}={count=10, sum=358.8999938964844}}
```

While the query works, when I translate to **gremlinpython** it's giving me the error of *"TypeError: Object of type GraphTraversal is not JSON serializable"*. (I'm unable to get around this issue, so I figure it best to modify the query that's causing the issue).

At a high level, I suspect if I change the output format then the issue could be solved.

With the chief question being, **is there a way to 'flatten' the grouped output?**

From this:

```
==>{{v0=v[2367552], v1=v[2343088], c=USD}={count=1, sum=12082.05}, ...}
```

Into this:

```
==>{{v0=v[2367552], v1=v[2343088], c=USD, count=1, sum=12082.05}, ...}
```

Or this:

```
==>{{v[2367552], v[2343088], USD, 1, 12082.05}, ...}
```

**Edit**

Turns out this is probably not to do with the output format. It seems to be the `group` command that's breaking it and causing the "JSON serializable" error. Strange query, but is there a way to group without using the group command?

Comment: You can add unfold() at the end of the query, to break the group map into its entries. This might do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do:

```
g.V(2367552, 2367728).as("v0").bothE().as("c").otherV().as("v1").
  select("v0","c","v1").
    by().
    by(valueMap("currency","trxn_amt").by(unfold())).
  group().
    by(select("v0","c","v1").
         by().
         by(select("currency"))).
    by(select("c").select("trxn_amt").fold()).unfold().
  map(union(select(keys).unfold(),
            select(values).
            project("count","sum").
              by(count(local)).
              by(sum(local)).unfold()).
      group().
        by(keys).
        by(select(values)))
```

It should be the most performant solution as only the first few steps (lines 1-4) actually query the data (and only the necessary data), the remainder of the query is processed in-memory and is just about the restructuring.

The result is a list of simple maps:

```
gremlin> g.V(2367552, 2367728).as("v0").bothE().as("c").otherV().as("v1").
......1>   select("v0","c","v1").
......2>     by().
......3>     by(valueMap("currency","trxn_amt").by(unfold())).
......4>   group().
......5>     by(select("v0","c","v1").
......6>          by().
......7>          by(select("currency"))).
......8>     by(select("c").select("trxn_amt").fold()).unfold().
......9>   map(union(select(keys).unfold(),
.....10>             select(values).
.....11>             project("count","sum").
.....12>               by(count(local)).
.....13>               by(sum(local)).unfold()).
.....14>       group().
.....15>         by(keys).
.....16>         by(select(values)))
==>[c:USD,count:1,v0:v[2367552],sum:12082.0595703125,v1:v[2343088]]
==>[c:USD,count:10,v0:v[2367728],sum:358.89999389648440,v1:v[2338888]]
```